# ASP.NET rewritten custom errors do not send content-type header

Tags: asp.net

I have the following configuration in my web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Error.html">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/Error.html" />
    <error statusCode="400" redirect="~/Error/Error.html" />
</customErrors>
```

FWIW, this is an ASP.NET MVC 3 application.

When I generate an error. For example by visiting..

```
http://testserver/this&is&an&illegal&request
```

.. which is blocked by ASP.NET request validation, the error page is returned, but there is no content-type header. IE infers the content and renders the HTML, however Firefix (correctly IMO) treats the content as text and displays the HTML code.

Are there additional steps that I need to take to persuade ASP.NET to send a content type header? I assume this is related to the fact that it's picking the files up from the file system, but the MIME types appear to be configured correctly on the server.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem. I am having the same problem. The content type should be set before serving the error page.

Comment: Nope, fraid not. The whole IIS errors thing really annoys me, it's a mess.

Comment: Ugh, I'm having the same issue and came across your question. I can't believe there's not more uproar about this.

Answer (score 7):

My ASP.NET MVC 2 application was sending the content-type header - Content-Type: text/html - correctly. Then it started giving this weird problem after upgrading the application pool from .Net Framework v2 to .Net Framework v4. I'm using the following configuration

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="/500.html">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="/404.html" />
</customErrors>
```

and I wanted to stick to static pages for my custom error pages.

The only solution I could think of was setting the header explicitly in the Application_Error method of the MvcApplication class in the Global.asax.cs file.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    // .
    // .
    // .
    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // .
        // Remember to set Response.StatusCode and
        // Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors
        // .
        Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        // .
        // .
        // .
    }
    // .
    // .
    // .
}
```

A bit annoying but the simplest solution that came to my mind.

Comment: I started with setting the ContentType in Global.asax and it worked, but then I found out that the problem was in missing custom error page for HTTP code 400. Once I created it and added it in web.config it started working out of the box and no changes in Global.asax were needed.

Answer (score 4):

With a static file error page, I have not found any solution.

Using a dynamic error page, headers are correctly set. But you may lose the error status code in the process and should then set it yourself in the error page code.
(That is somewhat the answer of rangitatanz, but maybe written more explicitly.)

So here is an example solution I use (webform way):

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/Error/unknown.aspx">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/404.aspx" />
    <error statusCode="400" redirect="~/Error/400.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

And in page load (here for the 404 one):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
    Response.StatusDescription = "Not found";
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
}
```

This could be used in a MVC project. If you do not want to mix webforms and MVC, you could write an error controller for that with its associated views. (That is indeed the way I go in my MVC project, but currently I am back on a webform one and so I have re-solved that using webform.)

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net wont' be sending this IIS will. If you want ASP.Net to send it then try add an Error.aspx and see what that looks like?

What I mean here is that you will be sent to an html page - which unless you have wired up IIS to run these through aspnet then it will just be served up normally.

If you add a new page error.aspx you can a) check if ASP.Net has fixed your issue or b) manually add your headers in there.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe that the customErrors section is for ASP.NET errors. Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx. My question is really, I want to server an HTML file when these IIS errors occur. I am able to do this, but it breaks in FF due to the lack of a content type header. How do I persuade IIS to send that header.

Comment: Yeah .. and what I was suggesting was to try see if ASP.Net would do it for you. Because I don't know how or why IIS is not sending the header.