# How to override all standard error pages in WebAPI

Tags: iis, error-handling, asp.net-web-api

My beautiful REST webservice works great. Except if I visit pages like `~/`, which returns the default IIS 403 Forbidden page (even using Fiddler and specifying only `Accept: application/json`). I want nothing but JSON or XML errors. Is there a way to override ALL exceptions with a custom exception handler? or a default controller to handle all unknown requests? What's the simplest, and the most correct (if different), way to handle this so that clients need only parse REST API-friendly XML datagrams or JSON blobs?

Example Request:

```
GET http://localhost:7414/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:7414
Accept: application/json, text/json, text/xml
```

Response: (that I don't like, notice that `text/html` wasn't one of the accepted response types)

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcaWNhcm9sXENoYXJpdHlMb2dpYy5pQ2Fyb2wuQXBp?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 25 Jan 2013 21:06:21 GMT
Content-Length: 5396

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title>IIS 8.0 Detailed Error - 403.14 - Forbidden</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 
...
```

Response (that I would prefer):

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: ...
Content-Length: ....

{
  "error":"forbidden",
  "status":403,
  "error_description":"Directory listing not allowed."
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit 1/26/14:** Microsoft just added "[Global Error Handling](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-web-api-21#global-error)" to the latest WebAPI 2.1 update.

---

Ok, I think I've got it. There's a few parts to it.

First: Create a controller for your errors. I named my actions according to the HTTP error codes.

```cs
public class ErrorController : ApiController {
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ActionName("Get")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get() {
        return Request.CreateErrorInfoResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, title: "Unknown Error");
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ActionName("404")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Status404() {
        return Request.CreateErrorInfoResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, description: "No resource matches the URL specified.");
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ActionName("400")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Status400() {
        return Request.CreateErrorInfoResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ActionName("500")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Status500() {
        return Request.CreateErrorInfoResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

Next, I created a `GenericExceptionFilterAttribute` that checks to see if the HttpActionExecutedContext.Exception is populated and if the response is still empty. If both cases are true, then it generates a response.

```cs
public class GenericExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute {
    public GenericExceptionFilterAttribute()
        : base() {
        DefaultHandler = (context, ex) => context.Request.CreateErrorInfoResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Internal Server Error", "An unepected error occoured on the server.", exception: ex);
    }

    readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<HttpActionExecutedContext, Exception, HttpResponseMessage>> exceptionHandlers = new Dictionary<Type, Func<HttpActionExecutedContext, Exception, HttpResponseMessage>>();

    public Func<HttpActionExecutedContext, Exception, HttpResponseMessage> DefaultHandler { get; set; }

    public void AddExceptionHandler<T>(Func<HttpActionExecutedContext, Exception, HttpResponseMessage> handler) where T : Exception {
        exceptionHandlers.Add(typeof(T), handler);
    }

    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context) {
        if (context.Exception == null) return;

        try {
            var exType = context.Exception.GetType();
            if (exceptionHandlers.ContainsKey(exType))
                context.Response = exceptionHandlers[exType](context, context.Exception);

            if(context.Response == null && DefaultHandler != null)
                context.Response = DefaultHandler(context, context.Exception);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            context.Response = context.Request.CreateErrorInfoResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, description: "Error while building the exception response.", exception: ex);
        }
    }
}
```

In my case, I went with a single generic handler that I could register support for each of the main exception types and map each of those exception types to specific HTTP response codes. Now register your exception types and handlers this filter globally in your `global.asax.cs`:

```cs
// These filters override the default ASP.NET exception handling to create REST-Friendly error responses.
var exceptionFormatter = new GenericExceptionFilterAttribute();
exceptionFormatter.AddExceptionHandler<NotImplementedException>((context, ex) => context.Request.CreateErrorInfoResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Not Implemented", "This method has not yet been implemented. Please try your request again at a later date.", exception: ex));
exceptionFormatter.AddExceptionHandler<ArgumentException>((context, ex) => context.Request.CreateErrorInfoResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, exception: ex));
exceptionFormatter.AddExceptionHandler<ArgumentNullException>((context, ex) => context.Request.CreateErrorInfoResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, exception: ex));
exceptionFormatter.AddExceptionHandler<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>((context, ex) => context.Request.CreateErrorInfoResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, exception: ex));
exceptionFormatter.AddExceptionHandler<FormatException>((context, ex) => context.Request.CreateErrorInfoResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, exception: ex));
exceptionFormatter.AddExceptionHandler<NotSupportedException>((context, ex) => context.Request.CreateErrorInfoResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Not Supported", exception: ex));
exceptionFormatter.AddExceptionHandler<InvalidOperationException>((context, ex) => context.Request.CreateErrorInfoResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid Operation", exception: ex));
GlobalConfiguration.Filters.Add(exceptionFormatter)
```

Next, create a catchall route to send all unknown requests to your new Error handler:

```cs
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultCatchall",
    routeTemplate: "{*url}",
    defaults: new {
        controller = "Error",
        action = "404"
    }
);
```

And, to wrap it all up, let IIS process all requests through ASP.NET by adding this to your `web.config`:

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Optionally, you could also use the `customErrors` section of the `web.config` to redirect all errors to your new error handler.

Comment: +1 Great answer.  It would be even better if you included the code you used for the `ExceptionFilterAttribute`.

Comment: Thanks @BrianRogers, I've added it above. Also a note about Microsoft's own work in this area in WebAPI 2.1.

Comment: MS's global error handling doesn't seem to be catching 400,403,404, etc. errors for me. Also, CreateErrorInfoResponse seems to be deprecated.

Comment: @Mark13426: The caching is an IIS Option (Dynamic Caching). I'll update this answer when I get time to upgrade to the latest version of WebAPI.

Comment: This is great, how come there isn't like this OOB still 4 yrs later? Are you still using this with WebAPI2 projects? ps With IIS7 and above its not recommended to `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />`

Comment: @JeremyThompson: I would. IIS default errors to human-readable HTML. If you want API-friendly REST errors, then you need to override it.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS Manager, you can [edit the custom errors](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771076%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

> Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to manage. For
>   information about opening IIS Manager, see Open IIS Manager (IIS 7).
>   For information about navigating to locations in the UI, see
>   Navigation in IIS Manager (IIS 7).
>
> In Features View, double-click Error Pages.
>
> On the Error Pages page, click to select the error you want to change.
>
> In the Actions pane, click Edit.
>
> In the Edit Custom Error Page dialog box, select one of the following:
>     Insert content from static file into the error response if your error
>   content is static, such as an .html file.
>
> Execute a URL on this site if your error content is dynamic, such as
>   an .asp file.
>
> Respond with a 302 redirect if you are redirecting a client browser
>   to a different URL.
>
> In the File path text box, type the path of the custom error page if
>   Insert content from static file into the error response is the chosen
>   path type. If using either the Execute a URL on this site or Respond
>   with a 302 redirect path type, type, instead, the URL of the custom
>   error page. Click OK.

See also [Rick Strahl's writeup](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Apr/29/IIS-7-Error-Pages-taking-over-500-Errors) which has some screenshots.

However, I don't think this will address the content-type header in the response--it just outlines how to change the *content* portion, which you could change to JSON format.  I don't know how to alter that without doing something more custom, but some clients will be able to handle the wrong content type if the content is still JSON, so this may be sufficient (and if so, may be your simplest option).  So this is not a complete answer, but it may help you.

There are other more code-intensive options--like a custom HTTP module or using server-side code/config (such as.Net) to handle all requests and build the correct response + headers (See [ASP.NET rewritten custom errors do not send content-type header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418021/asp-net-rewritten-custom-errors-do-not-send-content-type-header) or http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/runtime-extensibility/developing-iis-modules-and-handlers-with-the-net-framework).

Answer (score 0):

It may not work in all cases, but most.
An easier solution:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
</system.webServer>
```

Our 404 managed by our code (a real get to a REST entity that doesn't exist) works with that configuration.

You can also edit that setting from IIS management console, in "Error Pages" zone, on the right, "Edit Feature Settings..." link.
[image]