# Is there a simple way to replace the ASP.NET Web API HTML error page with a simple Error.json file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I feel like I may be over complicating things with a guide like this one:
[How to override all standard error pages in WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530387/how-to-override-all-standard-error-pages-in-webapi)

I couldn't get it to work because I think the version of ASP.NET Web API that I'm using has deprecated the `context.Request.CreateErrorInfoResponse()`

All I want to do is display an HTTP 403 Forbidden as a single static file located in `~/Error.json`

I've tried doing this to my Web.config file:

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error.json" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
```

And I've tried this too:

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On">
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error.json" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
```

It doesn't seem to have any effect at all when this exception is thrown:

```
throw new APIException(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, new MessageError("foobar"));
```

In my application, there will be only one situation where a Forbidden response is received, and I don't want my RESTful API to be returning an HTML response in this event.

What can I do to fix this?

The reason why I need to do this is to render the Web Application useless if a customer tries to crack or pirate this web application. I would like to do all of this within Startup.cs if it's possible to crash the app and to return a json response of the error rather than an HTML response that the `throw new Exception` method does by default.

Comment: Why not write `return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);` in your method or should it not even get that far? You could also write an ActionFilter to check for access rights and do the same thing but now apply that attribute to your methods where you want a forbidden check to occur.

Comment: If you have `IHttpActionResult` in your methods as return type in webapi.  Try `return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)` instead of throwing exception.

Comment: Isn't it possible just to modify the 500 Internal Server error HTML document returned by ASP.NET? I would like to replace the HTML document with a .json file.