# CustomErrors mode="On" is not redirecting to custom error page in ASP.Net Web API 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, custom-errors

I am trying create a customError page in our Web API Project. If any unhandlled error occurred in API I need to redirect to some custom page or if route is not available then also I need to redirect to some custom error page. To achieve this I have added following settings in web.config file.

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error"/>
</customErrors>
```

I have added Error.cshtml view in Shared folder. (Note: There is no Error controller in my project)

But if I hit any invalid path I am getting IIS setup 404 page. Please see the screen shot.[image]

Not sure, what exactly I am missing. 
Also If I attached a debugger, it is not coming to Application_Error method from Global.asax.cs (e.g. 404/501 errors). Surprising.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: custom error page is for the normal mvc controllers not for apiControllers, since api controllers does not refer to a view page

Comment: Then what is the option? How can I achieve above mentioned scenario?

Comment: the following links may help you:
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14656319/4437464) 
[link2](https://www.strathweb.com/2014/10/route-matching-overriding-404-asp-net-web-api/)

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue today and found a solution that may help you.
I guess that in your controller you are doing something like this :

```
 public ActionResult AddReport
    ... 
    if (something is bad...)
         return HttpNotFound("Hey you have some beautiful error here");
```

So this is returning excatly the screenshot you have included in your question.
Solution is to do it this way

```
  public ActionResult AddReport
    ... 
    if (something is bad...)
         return new HttpException(404, "Hey you have some beautiful error here");
```

***EDIT***

Based on you comment, this is not practical solution when you already have many controllers

In that case, you can try to edit your web.config and replace the  tag by this one

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="/Error.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
</httpErrors>
```

Happy coding !!

Comment: But then I have to do this for all action methods. This is not practical solution.